# Best Way To Create an "Add" View Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, modalviewcontroller

I have a table view that contains a list of Project objects.  When an item is selected it brings up a detail view. Pretty standard.  What is the best way to implement "add" functionality (popup a modal view controller to input new values and save the item)?

Currently I have view controllers for my root view, detail view, and add view.  Essentially the detail view and add view are exactly the same except for a save & cancel button in the add view.  Is it possible to reuse the detail view in the add view?

Finally, what is the best way to display the list of project properties in a grouped table view separated into sections?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you are already passing your detail view controller a managed object that it is supposed to display when in detail view mode. When the user decides to add a new project, just create a blank object, pass it to the detail controller and display it. (You might want to insert this blank object into another "empty" managed object context in case the user cancels the add process to avoid having to clean up your main managed object context in that case.)

The detail view controller would also need a flag that tells it whether it is in edit or add mode so it can adjust its controls (and possibly delegate messages it sends to its owner) accordingly. You would set the flag to the appropriate value before you display the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a UINavigationController.  The UINavigationController lets you push new view controllers on top of existing ones.  It gives you a navigation bar at the top that will allow the user to go back to the root controller.  I think it's the kind of controller Apple uses it in the default email application, to give you an example.

Concerning organization: you design your root view controller and a detail/add view controller.  In your app delegate, you attach a UINavigationController to the window and you set its root controller to the main controller you want to display.  That root controller can then push the add/detail controller onto the stack (and when it does so, it can tell the add/detail controller which types of button to display.)

I can't answer your grouped properties question, but it sounds like a separate question anyway.